# Parsing a document with separators and return named segments

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse a text which has different kinds of separators (e.g. `---` and `###`) I want to give those separators a name (`AW`, `FW` respectively) and further retrieve the content from one separator to the next plus the respective label.

For example:

```
test = """
0 test test test
---
1 test test test
1 test test test
###
2 test test test
---
3 test test test
###
4 test test test
"""
```

Should give:

```
[
    (None, '0 test test test'),
    ('AW', '1 test test test\n1 test test test'),
    ('FW', '2 test test test'),
    ('AW', '3 test test test'),
    ('FW', '4 test test test')
]
```

I have [tried the following pattern](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%3FP%3CAW%3E---)%7C(%3FP%3CFW%3E%23%23%23)&test_string=0%20test%20test%20test%0A---%0A1%20test%20test%20test%0A%23%23%23%0A2%20test%20test%20test%0A---%0A3%20test%20test%20test%0A%23%23%23%0A4%20test%20test%20test&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) (among others):

```
p = re.compile(r'(?P<AW>---)|(?P<FW>###)')

m = re.search(p, test)
print(m.groups())  # > ('---', None)
```

but I can't seem to be able to retrieve the relevant information.

---

#### Background

I want to parse email messages which have nested messages. The reason why I'm using regex here is because those separators are not always the same so I thought I may use some regex rule in order to detect them.

```
From: b@example.com
To: a@example.com

Of course!

---- Original Message ---
From: a@example.com
To: b@example.com

Lunch today?
```

---

#### Real world example

> **Note:** This data is publicly available ([Enron data set](http://www.enron-mail.com/email/)) - no censorship necessary

The task is to extract all three messages. The two separators here are

```
1) 
-----Original Message-----

2) 
---------------------- Forwarded by Vince J Kaminski/HOU/ECT on 05/02/2001 
05:16 PM ---------------------------
```

The raw string:

```
Message-ID: <19476677.1075856436259.JavaMail.evans@thyme>
Date: Wed, 2 May 2001 07:41:00 -0700 (PDT)
From: vince.kaminski@enron.com
To: loleary@riskwaters.com
Subject: RE: EPRM 2001 Houston
Cc: vince.kaminski@enron.com, tanya.tamarchenko@enron.com, 
    shirley.crenshaw@enron.com
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Bcc: vince.kaminski@enron.com, tanya.tamarchenko@enron.com, 
    shirley.crenshaw@enron.com
X-From: Vince J Kaminski
X-To: <loleary@riskwaters.com>
X-cc: Vince J Kaminski, Tanya Tamarchenko, Shirley Crenshaw
X-bcc: 
X-Folder: \Vincent_Kaminski_Jun2001_3\Notes Folders\Sent
X-Origin: Kaminski-V
X-FileName: vkamins.nsf

Kind Regards

-----Original Message-----
From: Vince.J.Kaminski@enron.com [mailto:Vince.J.Kaminski@enron.com]
Sent: 02 May 2001 15:38
To: loleary@riskwaters.com
Cc: Vince.J.Kaminski@enron.com
Subject: Re: EPRM 2001 Houston

Kind Regards

---------------------- Forwarded by Vince J Kaminski/HOU/ECT on 05/02/2001 
05:16 PM ---------------------------


Rakesh Bharati@ENRON
05/02/2001 04:31 PM
To: Vince J Kaminski/HOU/ECT@ECT
cc:  
Subject: Default Probability

Kind Regards
```

Comment: What about `0 test test test`?

Comment: @revo Sorry, you're right - idk if that is possible but this could be returned as `(None, 0 test test test)`.

Comment: Read your string line by line and use `startswith`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte It's not really as simple as that. I'm actually parsing email messages and the "separator patterns" do not really take the exact same form everytime. Idk if there are better options to do that.

Comment: So putting a real world input string, please put more complex conditions (nested and pounds) into it and update again.

Comment: @revo I've appended an email to my question.

Comment: Is the raw string always going to be a single mail which needs splitting into 3? Or is it a concatenation of several?

Comment: Please see this one https://regex101.com/r/KGya07/1